# Monitor USDT Deposits in Multiple Wallets on BSC

Tags: events, bsc, usdt

How to monitor USDT deposits in multiple smart contract wallets on binance smart chain (BSC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could monitor the real-time USDT deposit transactions using the Moralis streams API. All you need is to setup a streams with a webhook to receive the real-time data.

This is an example of how the code to set up monitoring event streams will look like. You can modify it to your requirement.

```
import Moralis from "moralis";
import { EvmChain } from "@moralisweb3/common-evm-utils";

Moralis.start({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
});

const ERC20_transfer_ABI = [{
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [
    { "indexed": true, "name": "from", "type": "address" },
    { "indexed": true, "name": "to", "type": "address" },
    { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" },
  ],
  "name": "transfer",
  "type": "event",
}]; // valid abi of the event

const options = {
  chains: [EvmChain.BSC], // list of blockchains to monitor
  description: "monitor all ERC20 transfers", // your description
  tag: "ERC20_transfers", // give it a tag
  abi: ERC20_transfer_ABI,
  allAddresses: true,
  topic0: ["transfer(address,address,uint256)"], // topic of the event
  advancedOptions: [
    {
      topic0: "transfer(address,address,uint256)",
    },
  webhookUrl: "https://YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL", // webhook url to receive events,
};

const stream = await Moralis.Streams.add(options);
const { id } = stream.toJSON(); // { id: 'YOUR_STREAM_ID', ...newStream }

// Now add the contract address which you want to monitor address with the stream
const address = "0x.."; 

await Moralis.Streams.addAddress({ address, id });
```

You can check Moralis docs or reach out to the moralis forum if you have any questions.

disclaimer: I work at Moralis

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Write monitoring script in Python, JavaScript. Programming knowledge is needed.
- Monitor all USDT ERC-20 Transfer events. [Some tutorials for event monitoring here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/index.html).
- From all events, filter events that have the target address matching your list

Comment: Thanks, could you please share a JavaScript code snippet?

Comment: No, I am here to answer your questions, not doing your work for you. If you want work then hire a contractor.